# My Account dashboard orders (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, account-dashboard

I am currently showing all my `orders` in `My Account` dashboard.
The problem only 5 orders are shown when I fetch all orders.

```
$_orders = $block->getOrders();
```

but I have 29 orders in the database, it only shows 5 orders.
How to get all the orders.

I have UI like this

[image]

When I fetch all order for dashboard section in `recent.phtml`
`/Magento/Sales/orders/recent.phtml` i only get 5 orders

whereas `/Magento/Sales/orders/history.phtml` i get all orders

I tried this

```
class Recent extends  \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Recent
{

/**
 * Limit of orders
 */
const YX_ORDER_LIMIT = 5000;


/**
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
 */
protected $_customerSession;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config
 */
protected $_orderConfig;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
private $storeManager;



protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->getRecentOrders();
}


private function getRecentOrders()
{

    $this->storeManager = ObjectManager::getInstance()
        ->get(StoreManagerInterface::class);

    $orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect(
        '*'
    )->addAttributeToFilter(
        'customer_id',
        $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId()
    )->addAttributeToFilter(
        'store_id',
        $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
    )->addAttributeToFilter(
        'status',
        ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()]
    )->addAttributeToSort(
        'created_at',
        'desc'
    )->setPageSize(
        self:: YX_ORDER_LIMIT
    )->load();
    $this->setOrders($orders);
}




}
```

It didnt work

Comment: Do you have all 29 orders with the same customer which you have logged in ?

Comment: @Mohitchauhan Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getOrders()` has a filter on order status and shows only the orders with status `visible_on_front = 1` (the field is in table `sales_order_status_state`). That excludes for example the status `pending_payment`.

So you can either set `visible_on_front = 1` for every status ore overwrite the block and change the `getOrder()` method.

For the recent orders there is a hard limit of 5 in the constructor. You should create a own block extending `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Recent`, implement there the `getOrders()` method (copy it from History block) and change the default Magento Block in the layout with your block.

Comment: All orders visible, I have orders tab also in my account, for orders tab it fetches all orders but for dashboard section ,  it only fetches 5 orders

Comment: see my updated question

Comment: ok, I have updated my answer - see the hard limit of 5 in Recent block

Comment: getOrders() function is only in Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History as i checked, not in  Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Recent

Comment: Magento has implicit setter/getter if there is no explicit method. For testing, just try to copy the method from History block into Recent block, delete everything except `parent::_construct();` from the `_construct()` method in Recent block and you will see all the orders will come :-)

Comment: If I just copy getOrders() method from the history to recent, it will work ? it will change the getRecentOrders() of recent whch has ORDER_LIMIT = 5 variable  ?

Comment: see my updated question

Comment: `getRecentOrders()` does not exist in standard Magento. The block Recent loads the collection with limitation to 5 in the constructor and stores the data (using the 'magic' method `setOrders($orders)`. Now you can either implement a `getOrders()` method as discussed (copied from History) or remove the limitation of 5 from constructor.

Comment: But limitation of 5 in recent only get  set in getRecentOrders function

Comment: ok if you have already custom block with custom method just remove `->setPageSize(
        self:: YX_ORDER_LIMIT
    )` and you are done :-) But with the large limit where was the problem?

Comment: Wait , I override this recent class to my custom class and override getRecentOrders function and instead of setPageSize 5 I set it to 5000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90568/discussion-between-helgeb-and-summu).